# Why does is my responsive website not responding to a mobile browser?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, responsive-design

My site is http://www.hificorder.com, and if you drag the browswer smaller in the desktop, you will see that it is responsive.

But if you load the browser in Safari on iPhone or on Chrome in Android, it renders eye-bleed small as if desktop client.

Why??

Comment: How to use `meta viewport`: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Comment: This is because your phone or tablet have as many pixels as there are in your desktop client, and if you have given each style in percentage only; without using the media queries then this thing happens. Read on for [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: @setek can you please explain how i should implement viewport. is it a meta tag?

Answer (score 4):

By Looking at your code I found that `You have to set the meta view port value`

Because you have to tell the browser to display the website content how it should fit into the screen

try this code

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Link : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/#toc-meta